# How can I return an integer value from a timer class - Java?

Tags: java, timer

so I am making a scoring system for my quiz game, and I wanted to base it like in kahoot, so that the more time you use to answer the question the less points you get. Here is the link to the website that illustrates the formula I tried making.

https://support.kahoot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002303908-How-to-toggle-points

However, I realized that I couldn't return from the timer class an integer value to perform my calculations. After researching I tried coming up with the following solution. I would create a timer class that would add 1 to a variable for 30 seconds, and would stopping adding 1 when the answer was chosen or the time ran out. With this, I could use the value in the variable class to perform my calculation. But I also encountered some problems, as either my variable only started adding 1 after the user chose the answer, or I couldn't make the timer stop after an answer was chosen. Below is the code I have. My question is if it is possible to return an integer from a timer, and if not, how can I change my code so it works?

```
    public boolean verifyAnswer(String userAnswer) {
    
    String correctAnswer = this.questions.get(currentQuestionIndex).correctAnswerText;
    
    Timer t = new Timer();
    
    int[] score = {0};
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(++score[0]);
            if (score[0] == 30) {
                t.cancel();
                
            }
            else if(userAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
                t.cancel();
            }
        };
    };
    
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);
    

    if(userAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
        
        timer.pauseTimer();
        
        long total = 0;
        long equation = score / 30000;
        long equation2 = equation / 2000;
        long equation3 = 1 - equation2;
        long point = equation3 * 1000;
        total += point;
        
        QuestionScreen label = new QuestionScreen(questions);
        JLabel label1 = label.label_2;
        label_2.setText(""+total);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Answer");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        timer.pauseTimer();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `verifyAnswer()`? Sequence should be: ask question, start timer, read user answer, stop timer, check answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. You want to return an int from a timer? Or you need help debugging your code and its counting?

Comment: The 30 second timer that appears for the user is in a different class, the timer which can be seen above is the one that appends 1 to a variable. My code does follow that sequence its just that I didn't paste it all here, as the only part I needed help was to check the answer.

Comment: @ControlAltDel could be either, which ever seems easier. Since I don't know how to return an int from a timer I decided to try a different route, but if you think that debugging my code is the way to go then that would be it for me.